# Opposite of ax.scatter.remove()?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a scatter plot in matplotlib

```
import matplotib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
scatter = ax.scatter([0], [0])
scatter.remove()  # remove the scatter from figure
```

Is there a method of `scatter` to add it (back) to the figure?

Comment: I believe you would have to re-add the scatter using ax.scatter([0], [0])

Comment: @Roars that works indeed, just curious to know if there's a way to re-add it without re-writing that line.

Comment: You could set it to invisible and then visible again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scatter is a `matplotlib.collections.PathCollection`. To add such a collection to an axes use `ax.add_collection`:

```
ax.add_collection(scatter)
```

Complete example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
scatter = ax.scatter([0], [0])
scatter.remove() 
ax.add_collection(scatter)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to actually remove it from the plot, you can instead set the scatter to be invisible using:

`scatter.set_visible(False)`

then later use:

`scatter.set_visible(True)`

to bring it back.

For example:

```
import matplotib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
scatter = ax.scatter([0], [0])
scatter.set_visible(False)

# Do something

scatter.set_visible(True)
```

Comment: Although not the answer I expected it's a good alternative to keep in mind.